# Java: Implementing a generic method which instantiates a collection of a particular type

Tags: java, generics, collections

I would like to implement a generic method which does something akin to the following:

```
private <T> void addToSize(ArrayList<T> list, Class<T> type, int size) {
    int currentSize = list.size();

    for(int i = currentSize; i < size; i++) {
        try {
            list.add(type.newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The method above works for something like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
addToSize(test, Integer.class, 10);
```

but I also want it to work for...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
addToSize(test, ArrayList.class, 10); //Is this possible?
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No - not possible with your current signature - there is no `ArrayList<ArrayList>.class`. Nice idea though

Comment: Are you aware of Arrays.fill()?  If you're willing to make your client produce a class object, why not make them produce a filler object instead.  That's more general anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern):

```
public interface Factory<T> {
    public T create();
}

private static <T> void addToSize( ArrayList<T> list, Factory<T> factory, int size ) {
    int currentSize = list.size();

    for ( int i = currentSize; i < size; i++ ) {
        list.add( factory.create() );
    }
}
```

Then for your example (implemented anonymously):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
addToSize( test2, 
    new Factory<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
       public ArrayList<Integer> create() { 
           return new ArrayList<Integer>( );
       }
    }, 10 ); // compiles
```

The cool thing about this is the class doesn't need a default constructor, and you could pass values into its constructor and/or use the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  The complexity of the `create()` method implementation is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
addToSize(test, (Class<ArrayList<Integer>>)(Class<?>)ArrayList.class, 10);
```

Class literals are always `Class` parameterized with the raw type. Getting it into a `Class` parameterized with something generic is somewhat tricky.